# Cambiar value de un input con jQuery o Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Deseo cambiar el valor escrito en 55 `inputs` que tienen la misma clase llamada `input_valores_provisionales` y distinto id (1,2,3,4...) en una función apenas se cargue la pagina

aqui el script

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 alert("alert para comprobar que la función se ejecuta"); // aqui OK

  $('.input_valores_provisionales').val("0"); // no funciona

});
```

he intentado de las siguientes formas y tampoco funciona

```
$('.input_valores_provisionales > input').val("0");
$(".input_valores_provisionales").text("0");
document.getElementsByClassName("input_valores_provisionales").value="0";
```

no obstante esta forma si funciona, y de una vez compruebo que la clase si esta bien escrita si no esto no haría efecto

```
$(".input_valores_provisionales").attr("placeholder","0");
```

pero no me sirve por que el cero no lo toma como valor numérico, es mas bien 'un cero fantasma' que se muestra ahí y desaparece al poner el cursor sobre el input, según esto el problema para mi, no esta en que el jquery no haga su función respectiva si no que pareciera que el input estuviera "bloqueado" para escribir en el mediante jquery o javascript, con el teclado puedo escribir normalmente

he intentado poner el atributo value="0" a cada uno de los 55 inputs y tampoco funcion

he intentado quitarle y agregarle el atributo type="text" y tampoco

¿Alguna idea de que puede ser?

Comment: Podrías agregar como ejemplo 1 de estos 55 input? Solo para ver la estructura/tipo de input. Y poder dejarte un ejemplo concreto

Comment: Actualizo su pregunta corrigiendo el error de sintaxis que mencioné en mi respuesta , después de esto debería funcionar correctamente como el ejemplo de mi respuesta. Si no hay detalles que no aparecen en la pregunta que interfieren con el resultado.

Comment: El problema es que tienes muchos inputs con la misma clase, si deseas obtener el valor de uno utiliza la función `eq()` de Jquery, intenta con algo como `$('.input_valores_provisionales').eq(0).val()`

Answer (score 8):

Tienes errores de sintaxis ? al parecer hace falta cerrar  el `ready` del document

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.input_valores_provisionales').val("0")
})  // <- falta el )
```

Así mismo recomiendo sustituir el ready actual por

```
$(function() {

});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.input_valores_provisionales').val("0")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input_valores_provisionales" id="1" value="21432"/>
<input class="input_valores_provisionales" id="2" value="24" />
<input class="input_valores_provisionales" id="3" value="q434"/>
<input class="input_valores_provisionales" id="4"  value="2143w2"/>
```

Comment: Solo por curiosidad: [_Así mismo recomiendo sustituir el ready actual por_] ¿Por qué motivo? ¿Es como una forma abreviada de usarlo?

Comment: @OscarR la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) lo recomienda v3 personalmente es la sintaxis que siempre uso.

Comment: Interesante, gracias por la aclaración!!